# Register generic type for each implementation of an interface

Tags: c#, autofac

Assuming I have the following types

```
public interface IBackgroundProcessor {}
public interface IBackgroundJob {}
public interface IStartupShutdownAction {}

public class BackgroundProcessor<TJob> 
    : IBackgroundProcessor 
    where TJob : IBackgroundJob 
    {}

public class BackgroundProcessorStartupShutdownAction<TProcessor> 
    : IStartupShutdownAction 
    where TProcessor : IBackgroundProcessor 
    {}
```

is there an easy way of registering a `BackgroundProcessor<>` for each `IBackgroundJob` in an assembly and a `BackgroundProcessorStartupShutdownAction<>` for each of the former?

Such that I can resolve `MyConcreteBackgroundJob`, `BackgroundProcessor<MyConcreteBackgroundJob>`, `IEnumerable<IBackgroundProcessor>` and `IEnumerable<IStartupShutdownAction>`

Currently, I do it like the following because I didn't find anything fitting in the docs, but I kinda think this pattern must be common enough that there is builtin support for it, and I just don't know about it:

```
public static void AddBackgroundJobs(this ContainerBuilder self,
                                     Assembly assembly)
{
  assembly.GetExportedTypes()
          .Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo<IBackgroundJob>() && !t.IsAbstract)
          .ForEach(registerJobProcessorAndAction);

  void registerJobProcessorAndAction(Type jobType)
  {
    var processorType = typeof(BackgroundProcessor<>)
                        .MakeGenericType(jobType);
    var actionType = typeof(BackgroundProcessorStartupShutdownAction<>)
                     .MakeGenericType(processorType);
    self.RegisterTypes(jobType, processorType, actionType)
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .AsSelf()
        .SingleInstance();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't give you a full answer, but I can point you here https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html . You might get what you want using those scanning features

Comment: @dglozano I know about these, but none of them seems to do what I need.

Comment: @travis-illig I guess this might be a good question for you, if I may be so bold :-)

Comment: If [RegisterGeneric](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components) doesn't get you what you need, there's nothing baked in.

Comment: nope, it doesn't - okay, then my extension method it is. thank you (once again), @TravisIllig